# Line breaks in .xcstrings catalog

Tags: xcode, localization, xcode15, xcstrings

I'm trying to add a line break to a string in the new Xcode 15 strings catalog, aka xcstrings. Thinking of nothing, I added the usual `\n` to the place where I want the line break.

But in my SwiftUI view I get to see the actual escaped `\n` and the text does not break lines. So the text "lorem ipsum\ndolor" gets presented to the user as "lorem ipsum\ndolor".

How can I create a text with intentional line breaks without using multiple independent strings in the catalog?

Comment: Try keeping Option while entering "new line/enter". I guess it should work. Also, look at the `.xcstrings` file in Finder, and Preview (or open it with a text editor, it's a JSON file), and compare what you see with manual entering of "\n" and the "Option" key technique. You'll notice that it's `\\n` (for manual) or just `\n` (with the Option) explaining why it failed on your attempt.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I tried both Shift+Enter and Ctrl+Enter, but not Option+Enter... and I really wanted to avoid always going back to editing the raw JSON

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Solution 1:
  Keep <kbd>Option</kbd> when adding a new line with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Solution 2:
  Edit manually the `xcstrings` (which is a JSON file).

If you open the `xcstrings` file with a text editor, or right click on it, `Open as`/`Source Code`, you'll see this:

```
{
  "sourceLanguage" : "en",
  "strings" : {
    "key1" : {
      "extractionState" : "manual",
      "localizations" : {
        "en" : {
          "stringUnit" : {
            "state" : "translated",
            "value" : "key1\n2"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "key2" : {
      "extractionState" : "manual",
      "localizations" : {
        "en" : {
          "stringUnit" : {
            "state" : "translated",
            "value" : "key2\\n2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "version" : "1.0"
}
```

On `key2`, I write explicitly in the interface "\n" as you tried, and on `key1`, I kept <kbd>Option</kbd> while typing new line.
Seeing in the source `\\n` explain why it's rendered once in the UI as visually `\n` and not a new line, since the backslash before the "n" is backslashed (ie escaped)